# Passing pointers as reference

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following code:

```
swap (int&x, int&y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y; 
    y = temp;
}
int main()
{
  int* x;
  int* y;

  *x = 5;
  *y = 6;

  swap(*x, *y);

  cout<< *x << *y;

}
```

The output is: 65

So the swap is successful. Pointer x now points to 6, and y points to 5.

Now if I change the swap call to this:

```
swap(x, y);
```

The output is still: 65

Which I don't understand. When I do:

```
swap(*x, *y);
```

I deference pointers x and y, and then pass in the values of x and y into the function as references. But when I do:

```
swap(x, y);
```

I didn't deference pointers x and y, and instead pass the memory address of pointers x and y into the functions as references.

Since in the first case I passed in values but in the second case I passed in the memory address, why would they return the same values and have the same behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: `int* x;` This defines an *uninitialized* pointer to an int. `*x = 5;` This invokes UB (undefined behavior) since the program writes to some random memory address which it doesn't own.

Comment: When posting code, please post your whole program

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Ignoring the fact that you never allocate memory for `x` and `y`, which is undefined behavior. This assumes that you do initialize them properly)</sub>

`x` points to memory location (let's say), `13`, which has a value of `5`.

`y` points to memory location `14`, which has a value of `6`.

When you `swap` them (note that you are using **`std::swap`**, and not your `swap` function), `x` will point to memory location `14`, and `y` will point to memory location `13`. So the values didn't change at all, just the pointers that point to them have.

It will only appear that they switched they values, but they didn't, they just pointed somewhere else.